# Can a cousin be my financial sponsor to obtain long term Spain student visa?

Tags: visa, student-visa, indian-citizens, spain, india

I have been accepted in an institute in Barcelona for a 1-year long course. I now have to apply for a long term Spanish student visa in India. One of the documents required for visa purpose is financial support. My parents are not in a situation to do this. But my maternal cousin is willing to help and support me financially. Now, will this cause any trouble as he is not an immediate family member? The local consulate said I have to prove our relationship ties. How can I do that? Will a letter or affidavit of support suffice? Please help.

Comment: For questions regarding long-term residence, please ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.